# Call C# Function from VB Script Not working

Tags: c#, com, vbscript, tridion, tridion-2011

VB Script is not calling the c# method from the workflow. Am i doing correct? I am able to test the same code from the server.

```
Option Explicit
Dim testwfhandler
Set testwfhandler= CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")
If Not testwfhandler Is Nothing Then    
Call testwfhandler.test()    
End If
Set testwfhandler= Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been dealing with a similar issue for the last couple of days.

I's without any doubt a problem with the registration.

In my case I registered the assembly using the regasm located in:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

The workflow agent is a 32 bits application, so I just registered the assembly with the regasm executable located in:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

And worked like a charm

Also make sure you build your dll to work with Any CPU

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an issue with your Assembly registration. Did you "just use" RegAsm, or did you use RegAsm /codebase?

Anyway, search your registry for "CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler". You should find a key with a large GUID and underneath there should be a series of other Registry keys. One of these will be called InProcServer32, and inside you should find a few string values, including "Assembly" and "Codebase".

If you find the key, double check that the values are correct. If you don't find the key, try registering your assembly again with `RegAsm /codebase <path to your assembly>`

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I have registered RegAsm /codebase. and I am able to find the entry in Registry. Under InProcServer32, 1.Assembly = CoreComponentWorkflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21f061a704295678 2. Codebase = file:///F:/Workflow-Server/CoreComponentWorkflow/bin/Debug/CoreComponentWorkflow.DLL 3. Class=CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler 4. Runtimeversion = v4.0.30319 5. ThreadingModel = Both. 6. Default=mscoree.dll For all the 6 entries, the type is "REG_SZ" and Key Name is "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{37703D4A-7F28-3A36-9E83-03B2BA07E977}"

Comment: This is the GUID in my assemblyinfo.cs file 928693b3-74ad-44df-b084-6df7c65c1832. And I am able to find the above details in couple of places in the registry. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: "ActiveX component can't create object" is probably one of the most generic errors ever. Have you tried putting something in your constructor to prove it gets called? Can you attach to the workflow service and try to debug it? Maybe you could try to write to a file to make sure your code is at least being invoked?

Comment: I am tying to write text file in C#, that is also not working, It seems that C# code is not called from the VB.

Comment: Nuno, Can you please guide me to debug the workflow bit briefly? is there any guide/steps/docs?

Comment: Please do read this chapter about workflow: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_BC4CC8F01AAF47B68B68D177AAC99AB1 Sorry, I don't have time to guide you through this. You can always contact us or one of our partners for training/assistance.

Comment: Sure Vin, I have gone through already,  but could not find any topic related to Debug. Anyway will take a look on this in detail.

Comment: Debugging has nothing to do with workflow, you must understand what you're doing before you start thinking about Tridion & Workflow. Focus on the COM/.NET side of it, this is where you're having trouble. You created a com-visible .NET assembly and the workflow service can't call it. This is where your issue is. Not Tridion. Not workflow. One step at a time and you'll get there.

Comment: Yes, I Understand that as of now the problem is with COM object side, but am getting troube when i try to do something from the workflow script editor. At the same time am to test the same VB Script code from the server directly. This means i have registerd the the dll correctly and getting the com object. but not from Tridion Workflow script editor.

Comment: Your VBscript code attempts to instantiate the COM object and fails. The error message is **very** clear about that. So your machine and you have some disagreement as to whether you "registered the DLL correctly". Which must means that apparently that place you have it in the registry is **not** where the workflow service/interop is looking. Did you try checking in procmon to see which registry location is being accessed?

Comment: @Frank: How can i check whether the DLL registered in the correct place at registry? My DLL are registered in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE locaton in registry, and Where the workflow service is looking? I will explore the details to used process monitor.

Comment: @Frank: I found that "TCMWorkflowAgent" service is placed in "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE location. My dlls are also placed in the above 2 location.

Comment: Procmon can show you what  registry keys are being accessed by what process. So that should allow you to answer both of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your VB appears to be fine.  Make sure you:
1) register your assembly (using RegAsm) or place it in the GAC.
2) set the ProgId in your code to "CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler". Here is some more info on ProgIds: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Am sure, I have registered using RegAsm.exe ( I have tested creating com object using vb script code in the server, it is working fine) and i have used te ProgId as well, and set comvisible also True. The abov code is workfing fine from the server (when i excecute as .vbs file) but it is not working when from the workflow script editor.

Comment: Check the event viewer and paste here the error message please.

Comment: are you referring "Open Event Log" from the administration tab in CME?

Comment: I was actually referring to the Tridion log in the Tridion server's Event Viewer.

Comment: An error occurred while executing the Workflow script.
The Script Engine returned the following information:

SOURCE:

  Line = 3
  Column = 0
  Number = 429
  Source = Microsoft VBScript runtime error

  Description = ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler'
  HelpContext = 0
caused by: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
and description: ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler'

Source:
LogScriptError